# Why are my users getting this AWS-related error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native

I apologize for not providing that much detail but there is nothing I can do about it.
I have a React Native app hooked up with Sentry a crash analytics tool and I have been getting this crash report lately with no trace to its cause:

> Error: Could not download from 'https://d1wp6m56sqw74a.cloudfront.net/~assets/a9df2c73b9dd467f9205fdc02ab3828f'

The error seems to be coming from a React Native library as indicated [here](https://sentry.io/share/issue/4ac63b0522e441c7bbbf9879e5fadc45/) by Sentry.

The link in the error points to one of many images stored locally inside the project bundle files.

I have done some searching and found out that this error is related to AWS. So the question is what in the world are my local images doing in AWS ? !!

Comment: That link is pointing to a Game of Thrones jpg file.

Comment: Actually the image when downloaded gives an image of a robot: https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZitJ21RM36kkUHfSeteeIVl43iofxSjpWOgUBhaVlZ7l8oV8HXAwWVhMdVmR1Lykkd222VLYcuIgfkWx1gSirEQ2E9342AqpoXrTgMjDNOFA_1yzhW1mJTTKT-rfmhT-k7W43io76emXCbgKYTq9KgfB_12KHtXo1TIu22Vl2r338aUCvly2xF_1MSJ1CESRsHeNFqOqGZ6jmlbssYaPdUYU_1lJJDTI_1DwaTugPlA5MAkPTxQVH_1WfClAci8UfzJT3_1nBAqxrWavCegNikj-sOX1_1tHgVHp_10szUCBynH33tu70Nii0xuGxS6C_1BIKc34zt9wthxcpHvRIs9wa_1TqNFoz2xo6l5Rw&hl=en-CA @Ahmed, is this issue persisting? it seems access to this object is public

Comment: @Deiv this is one of images that are stored locally inside the project files ... What AWS has to do them ?

Comment: The fact that it's going through cloudfront means whatever you're using to host is hosting it through AWS, and so your files get uploaded and called through cloudfront

Comment: @Deiv I am using Expo with React Native ... are you saying that Expo uploaded project bundle to AWS ?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Expo, but from a quick search from what I understand it lets you deploy your React project? In that case yes, it is going through AWS to host your project, which makes sense. A lot of hosting solutions go through AWS in the background.

Comment: As to why you get that error, I'm really not sure, but it doesn't have anything to do with AWS (as we can manually download this file easily), more likely something wrong with the app

Comment: Added a comment so we can close this question (I recommend you open a new question to investigate the issue from a react perspective)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the source of the problem appears to be caused by the app host which is Expo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the React project is hosted through Expo which uses AWS in the background, which explains why the error is on an object on CloudFront.

Additionally, the object is accessible directly through the link, which means the issue is not related to AWS but more so the react project itself or an issue with the deployment through Expo.

Answer (score 0):

When the user is offline, Sentry will throw that error and will send it to you once the user has a connection. I believe you should check whether or not the user has internet connection before downloading the asset.